# How to get a numeric vector from a list of numbers?

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
> Lst<-list(1,2,3,4,5)
> mode(Lst[1])
[1] "list"
```

I want to extract elements 1 to 3 into a vector the mode of which is numeric. I can get 3 containers as a list or each element seperately, but I can't get 3 elements as a numeric vector:

```
> mode(Lst[1:3])
[1] "list"
> mode(Lst[[1]])
[1] "numeric"
> mode(Lst[[1:3]])
Error in Lst[[1:3]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

Comment: `unlist(Lst[1:3])`?

Comment: or   `as.numeric(Lst[1:3])`

Comment: `purrr::flatten_dbl(Lst[1:3])` will ensure you get doubles (numerics) back as well in the spirit of `unlist` but with much more safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast them as `numeric`:

```
> a <- as.numeric(Lst[1:3])
> a
[1] 1 2 3
> mode(a)
```

Also see: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_between_vector_types/